# IOS: manage viewcontrollers inside a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I set a navigation controller in this way:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationcontroller"];
        NSArray *viewCS = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstViewController, secondCureViewController, thirdUpViewController,fourthViewController, nil];
        [navController setViewControllers:viewCS];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In this way when I open my navigation controller, it appear in fourt viewcontroller and its ok, but what are the instructions to navigate inside my navigation controller?

Example: I'm in fourth and I want to go in first, after I want to go in second and after I want to go another time in four.

Naturally I don't want to lost the current states of my viewcontrollers, can you help me?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of what you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below methods to move between navigation controller.s

```
– pushViewController - add new view controller in hierarchy.
– popViewControllerAnimated - From 4th to 3rd view controller.
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated: - from 4th to 1st view controller.
```

EDIT:  NSArray *viewCS - > declare this as a member variable or property of App Delegate.
Then you can access array from delegate as below when you want to push or pop a view. This way all controllers will remain in your array and can be added/removed as required.

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: yes, but when I use pop my navController.viewControllers in nslog decrease of a viewcontroller and there are three viewcontrollers and not four

Comment: I tried and I have a crash that say "'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'"

Comment: can you update your question with the code that you have put as part of app delegate and then when you are trying to pop a view? Object is getting released. By looking at the code I will be able to help..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of navController's viewControllers array.

```
NSArray *VCArray = [navController viewControllers];
//manipulate VCArray and change the order of its items
...
//set it as new viewControllers array
[navController setViewControllers:VCArray animated:YES];
```

That way, view controllers in navigation stack keep their states and none of them is released.

Answer (score 0):

I did bellow code...

```
// Get controllers                   
 NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

int viewIndex = 2;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewIndex] animated:NO];
```

Comment: I noticed that when I use pop viewcontrollers began three and not four

Comment: if you want to go first view from 4th then set viewIndex as 1,
viewIndex = 1